# Não permitir repetir valores em DropDownList diferentes usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algoritmo

Eu tenho 3 `DropDownList` onde os mesmos tem 4 itens com o mesmo `valor` (1,2,3,4). Eu preciso respeitar q cada `DropDownList` não repita o valor selecionado nos outros.

Exemplo:

```
ddl0= 1 
ddl1= 2 (não permitiria escolher os valores 1 e 3)
ddl2= 3 (não permitiria escolher os valores 1 e 2)

*ddl= DropDownList
```

Eu consegui fazer com 2 DropDownList dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#ddl0").on('change', function () {
  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $("#ddl1 option[value='1']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='2']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='3']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='4']").prop("disabled", false);

 } else if ($(this).val() == '2') {
    $("#ddl1 option[value='1']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='2']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='3']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='4']").prop("disabled", false);

 } else if ($(this).val() == '3') {
    $("#ddl1 option[value='1']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='2']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='3']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='4']").prop("disabled", false);

 } else if ($(this).val() == '4') {
    $("#ddl1 option[value='1']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='2']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='3']").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#ddl1 option[value='4']").prop("disabled", true);

    }
   });
 });
```

agora entrando com um terceiro DropDownList. Como conseguiria fazer para nenhuma das ddls ficarem com valores repetidos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma função genérica, em vez de repetir vários if's. Fiz da forma abaixo que creio que resolve (veja os comentários no código com algumas explicações). Também coloquei uma propriedade CSS com fundo vermelho para os options desabilitados para melhor ilustração no exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   // seleciona todos os ddls que começam com o id "ddl"
   var ddls = $("[id^=ddl]");

   ddls.on("change", function(){
      
      // declara a array
      var slots = [];
      
      // busca option selecionado nas ddls
      var opts = ddls.find("option:selected");

      // laço para alimentar a array com os values selecionados
      opts.each(function(){

         var v = $(this).attr("value");

         // só inclui na array values com algum valor
         if(v) slots.push(v);

      });
      
      // redefino a variável opts, agora com todos os options
      opts = ddls.find("option");
      opts.each(function(){

         var t = $(this);
         
         // desabilita o option se o seu value estiver na array e não esteja selecionado
         t.prop("disabled", ~slots.indexOf(t.attr("value")) && !t.is(":selected") ? true : false);

      });

   });
   
});
```

```css
option:disabled{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddl0">
   <option>...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="ddl1">
   <option>...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="ddl2">
   <option>...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Abaixo o código "limpo":

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var ddls = $("[id^=ddl]");
   ddls.on("change", function(){
      var slots = [];
      var opts = ddls.find("option:selected");
      opts.each(function(){
         var v = $(this).attr("value");
         if(v) slots.push(v);
      });
      opts = ddls.find("option");
      opts.each(function(){
         var t = $(this);
         t.prop("disabled", ~slots.indexOf(t.attr("value")) && !t.is(":selected") ? true : false);
      });
   });

});
```

Comment: Ficou ótimo, foi de grande ajuda sua explicação. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Cada vez que ocorrer o evento `change` de um `select`, você cria um `Array` com todos os valores que já foram marcados.

Depois, você pode usar o método `$.inArray()` para desabilitar os `options` cujos valores estejam neste `Array`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let s = $('select[id^=ddl]'), o = s.children();    
  s.change(function() {        
    let valores = [];    
    s.find('option[value]:selected').each(function() { valores.push($(this).val()); });        
    $(o).each(function() {
      $(this).prop('disabled', $.inArray(this.value, valores) !== -1);      
    });    
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddl0">
   <option>...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="ddl1">
   <option>...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="ddl2">
   <option>...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda LLeon.